# Tableview refresh/reload like in Reminders app in iOS5

Tags: ios, uitableview

I built an app that displays a tableview. If the user tap an entry it goes to the detailed screen. In the detail screen, I have a button to delete this entry. I delete the record from the datasource and go back to the previous screen (the one with table view). I can create a refresh button and call the reloadData method, which is working fine. However, I would like to eliminate refresh button and it refresh the data automatically. Like in the new app in iOS 5 called reminders. I can tap the task and it goes to the details screen. If I delete the task in the details screen, it will go back to the previous screen and the records has been removed from the display automatically.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just call [table reloadData] when you delete the item.

Answer (score 0):

```
whenever you enter the tableview from detailview override viewwillappear delegate 

 -(void)ViewWillAppear
 {
    [tableview reloadData];
}
```